# Can I have a common SCSS in one project which can be imported in multiple projects

Tags: css, sass, angular6, angular8

Technology: Angular 8
Current Requirement
I have 3-4 projects which will share common stylesheet and style guide. Is it possible to create a project with common SCSS and import in all other 4 angular projects? If not please let me know the best way to achieve this thing.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm packages for it, and add it like that.
If you do not which to use npm packages, you could maybe extract that SCSS into its own git repo and use git clone in CI or something to add it automatically to that repo.

Comment: Can you please explain it further